# Loop this ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax

On my invoice form, users have the ability to click on a button to add as many parts as the want and then the code below automatically fills in the part description and part price.

I tried to loop it but its not working, instead i added multiple scripts for partnumber1, partnumber2, partnumber3 etc.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( "#partstable" ).on( 'blur keyup', "#partnumber" , function() {

searchString=$(this).val();

   var data = 'partnumber='+searchString;

   if(searchString) {
       // ajax call

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "partpricequery.php",
           data: data,

          success: function(html){ 

result = String(html).split("|"),

$("#partdescription").val(result[0]);
$("#partprice").val(result[1]);

showlabel ();

         }
       });    
   }
   return false;
});

</script>
```

2nd one

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( "#partstable" ).on( 'blur keyup', "#partnumber1" , function() {

searchString=$(this).val();

   var data = 'partnumber='+searchString;

   if(searchString) {
       // ajax call

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "partpricequery.php",
           data: data,

          success: function(html){ 

result = String(html).split("|"),

$("#partdescription1").val(result[0]);
$("#partprice1").val(result[1]);


showlabel ();

         }
       });    
   }
   return false;
});

</script>
```

3rd

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$( "#partstable" ).on( 'blur keyup', "#partnumber2" , function() {

searchString=$(this).val();

   var data = 'partnumber='+searchString;


   if(searchString) {
       // ajax call

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "partpricequery.php",
           data: data,

          success: function(html){

result = String(html).split("|"),


$("#partdescription2").val(result[0]);
$("#partprice2").val(result[1]);

showlabel ();

         }
       });    
   }
   return false;
});

</script>
```

This is how i tried to loop it but again its not working

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var count = 0;
$( "#partstable" ).on( 'blur keyup', "#partnumber"+count , function() {

searchString=$(this).val();

   var data = 'partnumber='+searchString;

   if(searchString) {
       // ajax call

       $.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "partpricequery.php",
           data: data,

          success: function(html){ 

result = String(html).split("|"),

var counter=0;
loop{
$("#partdescription"+counter).val(result[0]);
$("#partprice"+counter).val(result[1]);
counter++;
}

showlabel ();

         }
       });    
   }
   return false;
});

</script>
```

Comment: you mean `for (var count = 0; count < 3; count++) $("#partstable").on('...', '#partnumber" + count, ...);`?

Comment: i dont want multiple scripts, i just want one. And no matter how many input fields they add, the user can type in the part number and it will auto fill the description and price. Even if the user adds 20 input fields.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the count variable will have the value after the last execution. Here is an experiment to verify ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/btfkacot/)):

```
for (var count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
  $('#btn' + count).on('click', function() {alert(count);});
}
```

Assuming there are 3 buttons with ids btn0, btn1 and btn2, but no matter which button you click the alert will always show 3 (the value after the loop finishes).

One ugly workaround is to create the function with the `Function` function ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/btfkacot/2/)):

```
Function("alert(" + count + ");")
```

Or you can create an anonymous function ([link](https://jsfiddle.net/btfkacot/1/)):

```
for (var count = 0; count < 3; count++) {
 (function(count) {
  $('#btn' + count).on('click', function() {alert(count);});
 })(count);
}
```